# Scheduling task execution based on previous execution

Tags: java, cron

I want to execute my utility (to do some cleanup tasks) continuously. Next execution should start as soon as the current one finished successfully.

I can't use the Java scheduler or Crontab as I don't know the execution interval in advance. One option is updating the database after every successful execution and inspecting it before each execution.

Is there any better option to do this?

My utility is written in Java.

Comment: You could try to run tasks recursively. If task finishes successfully it will start another instance of cleanup task and so on. You could use java quartz scheduler ti schedule initial task at any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your can install **run-one** utility in your system.

> run-one is a wrapper script that runs no more than one unique instance of some command with a unique set of arguments.
>
> This is often useful with cronjobs, when you want no more than one copy running at a time.

More information on how to use run-one utility [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/02/introducing-run-one-and-run-this-one.html). It can be combined with cron:

```
*/60 * * * *   run-one your-program arg1 arg2
```